# Setfocus property(Using custom autocomlpetion, I set the focus to auotoCompleteList at the time of adding this list as child)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I set the focus to auotoCompleteList at the time of adding this list as child but at the time of remove this popup i am getting whole text in textInput as selected with black background iwant to set the focus to this text field but not to select whole typed text.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution if anyone need this then use below code

//first set selection
textInput.setSelection(textInput.text.length+1,textInput.text.length+1);
// then set focus
textInput.setFocus();
//and then use this to show cursor
flash.ui.Mouse.show() ;